# sqlite3_exec not commit immediately

Tags: c++, sqlite

Using sqlite3_exec on an embedded system. I require the write to be done asap, so if the power is lost, the data is saved. However I've found the machine must be on for ~10 seconds before the data is fully written!  Is there a setting to try and speed it up?

Using journal mode DELETE ("PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE;), and Synchronous mode FULL ("PRAGMA synchronous=FULL;").

I've tried sending "BEGIN;" and "COMMIT;" before and after the UPDATE, respectively.  No change.

```
std::ostringstream oss;
std::ostringstream oss_err;
oss << "UPDATE " << sTableName << " SET " << pon_rstc_db[LookupParamIndex(param)].column_name << "='" << sValue << "';";

if (!isDatabaseOpen())
    OpenDatabase(sDatabaseName);

if (isDatabaseOpen())
{
    char* db_err = 0;
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, oss.str().c_str(), NULL, 0, &db_err);
    if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        bResponse = true;
    }
    else
    {
        oss_err << db_err;
        oss_err << "Update failed for " << LookUpColumnName(param) << ". Data not saved.";
        DisplayError(oss_err.str());
        bResponse = false;
    }
    sqlite3_free(db_err);
    db_err = 0;
}
else
{
    DisplayError("executing statement while database closed");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to delete the journal.  My understanding is that the journal will recover uncommitted data in case of a failure.  Has your testing shown otherwise?

Comment: @Atif [`PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) means that SQLite will delete the journal after a _successful_ commit, as opposed to keeping it around or truncating it. The only dangerous modes are `MEMORY` and `OFF`.

Comment: @tda Please create a [mcve]. Are you using transactions at all, and forgetting to commit them? Did you try reading the results back immediately after writing them?

Comment: Why not leave the journal to the default mode?  Is the performance the same with the default journal setting?

Comment: What embedded system? What file system? Are you using a custom VFS?

Comment: @Atif  1. Correct journal never recovers uncommitted data during a failure (power loss, etc.)

Comment: @Atif  2. The myDatabase.db has a myDatabase.db-journal file created during a transaction. If not committed, it will remain (such as during a failure).  During bootup of my device, I now perform a check and delete any uncommitted data by deleting the myDatabase.db-journal file
3. Isn't journal_mode delete the default setting?

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two  1. Yes, in another section I am performing a BEGIN; sqlite3_prepare, sqlite3_step and COMMIT;  As for the sqlite3_exec command, my understanding was it performed the entire transaction at once.
I will see if I can provide a better example. Thanks for warning on MEMORY and OFF

Comment: @CL operating system/file system is same as ubuntu 14.04 trusty tahr

Comment: Deleting the `-journal` file is the worst thing you can do; this leaves the partial transaction in the database. To rollback the interrupted transaction, just open the database.

Comment: What embedded system? What kind of disk?